# Notation for integers modulo $n$

Tags: notation, soft-question

Is there an alternative (simplified) way to write $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ for the integers modulo $n$?

In the document I write, the integers modulo $n$ appear so often that the quotient notation becomes quite cumbersome. Unfortunately, the notation $\mathbb Z_p$ is already used for the $p$-adic integers, and I'd like to avoid it.

I know that I could choose whatever notation I like, but I think it is always best to use already existing notation in case it exists.

Note that also $\mathbb Z/(n)$ is in quotient notation, and I would like to avoid it.

Comment: When you say cumbersome, do you mean cumbersome for you to type in $\TeX$? Or that it virtually clutters the finished document for your readers?

Comment: Cumbersome in the visual sense. For instance in expressions like $(a_i)_{i\in(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)^\times}$, and they might get more complicated. Having a simplified way of writing $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ would visually help.

Comment: IMO, I find $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ to be the best way to represent the set of integers modulo $n$. If you find yourself typing that set a lot, you could mention in your document something like, "For simplicity's sake, let $A = \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$."

Comment: Perhaps $(C_n,+)$, though it's kind of weird. Or use some self-defined notations like $[n]$ or $[\![n]\!]$.